# VBA Access Force Form Update to show new records added

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, insert

I have an Access database with two Forms. 
Form 1 (Single Form) is designed to browse records from Table 1.
Form 2 (Continuous Form) is designed to browse records from Table 2.
On Form 2, I created an "Import" button, linked to an Event Procedure.
This procedure selects current record from Table 2 and inserts it Into Table 1.

Problem is, the newly inserted record is not shown dynamically on Form 1.
Form 1 needs to be closed and reopened in order for the change to be visible. 
Is there a better way to do this "refresh"? From code?

Comment: Simply use [Form.Requery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-requery-method-access).

Comment: Why are you duplicating data?